# Json and parsing C#

Tags: json.net

I need your help. I am new to C#, so I would appreciate any help!
So I made a program which parses a json file and puts it into an object. 
My program looks like this:

```
var path = (@"C:\sim\input7.json");
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path))
{
   JObject SimData = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
   Console.WriteLine("Object ID: " + SimData["_id"]);
   Console.WriteLine("ID: " + SimData["id"]);
   Console.WriteLine("Day: " + SimData["day"]);
   Console.WriteLine("Value: " + SimData["value"]);
```

First I use only one line in my json file and it works fine.
Now i have multiple lines, such as:

```
{ "_id" : "_id1" , "id" : "100", "day" : "5", "value" : "90.38", "time" : "000000" }
{ "_id" : "_id2", "id" : 100, "day" : 5, "value" : 89.79000000000001, "time" : "000100" }
```

My question is, what to do if I want to `Console.WriteLine();` each value for example!

I tried few thing, but a can't work this out. I have same input file.  I tried this now:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
                 {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                     {
                        list.Add(line);
                        JObject SD = JObject.Parse(line);
                        Console.WriteLine(SD["day"]);
                     }
              }
```

want to write out only "value" for each line!

Comment: Should all values not be quoted in JSON? If so, then line 2 is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Parse each JSon file separatly :

```
foreach(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\sim\").getDirectories());
{
   using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(directoryInfo.FullName))
{
   JObject SimData = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
   Console.WriteLine("Object ID: " + SimData["_id"]);
   Console.WriteLine("ID: " + SimData["id"]);
   Console.WriteLine("Day: " + SimData["day"]);
   Console.WriteLine("Value: " + SimData["value"]);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but sadly this doesn't work for me! SimData[0]["_id"]); this should point to first line, write? Do you maybe have any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: And error appears in JObject SimData JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine()); with comment: Invalid property identifier character: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: Another solution is to create multiple mini json file with a JSon in each of file and read them.

Comment: I know a ask a lot, but can you just push me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a proper json file it will be easier to read (and cleaner) :

```
{ "_id" : "_id1" , "id" : "100", "day" : "5", "value" : "90.38", "time" : "000000" }
{ "_id" : "_id2", "id" : 100, "day" : 5, "value" : 89.79000000000001, "time" : "000100" }
```

This is not json

```
[{ "_id" : "_id1" , "id" : "100", "day" : "5", "value" : "90.38", "time" : "000000" },
{ "_id" : "_id2", "id" : 100, "day" : 5, "value" : 89.79000000000001, "time" : "000100" }]
```

This is a json array.

If you can have this json file then you can easly read it as a list using `Json.Net` creating a class for the objects you are parsing :

```
public class IdObject
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int day { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
}
```

Then :

```
List<IdObject> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IdObject>>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(list[0]._id);
```

*result : _id1*